# php form to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some trouble figuring out how to post data from a form into mysql table.
Initially I tried to create an insert query with my 2 arrays like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_form ($fields) VALUES ('$str')";
```

but it was complaining about array to string conversion php error.

Here is my php code:

```
$fields = [
    'requested_effective_date', 'employer_group_name', 'group_number', 'billing_mode', 'other', 'proposed_name_insured', 'ssn', 'member_number', 'sex', 'age',
    'birth_date', 'daytime_phone_number', 'home_address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'jobtitle_occupation', 'hours_worked_per_week',
    'date_hired', 'beneficiary_name_relationship', 'proposed_name_insured_activity', 'used_tobacco_products', 'email_address', 'spouse',
    'sex_spouse', 'spouse_dob', 'children1', 'sex_children1', 'children1_dob1', 'children2', 'sex_children2', 'children2_dob2', 'children3', 'sex_children3', 'children3_dob3',
    'children4', 'sex_children4', 'children4_dob4', 'plan_units_of_coverage', 'plan_modal_premium', 'total_premium_due',
    'coverage_type', 'riders', 'section_125', 'name_of_company', 'replacement', 'plans_option'
];

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$field])) {
        $_POST[$field] = null;
    }
}

$formData = [
    'requested_effective_date' => $_POST['requested_effective_date'],
    'employer_group_name' => $_POST['employer_group_name'],
    'group_number' => $_POST['group_number'],
    'billing_mode' => $_POST['billing_mode'],
    'other' => $_POST['other'],
    'proposed_name_insured' => $_POST['proposed_name_insured'],
    'ssn' => $_POST['ssn'],
    'member_number' => $_POST['member_number'],
    'sex' => $_POST['sex'],
    'age' => $_POST['age'],
    'birth_date' => $_POST['birth_date'],
    'daytime_phone_number' => $_POST['daytime_phone_number'],
    'home_address' => $_POST['home_address'],
    'city' => $_POST['city'],
    'state' => $_POST['state'],
    'zip' => $_POST['zip'],
    'jobtitle_occupation' => $_POST['jobtitle_occupation'],
    'hours_worked_per_week' => $_POST['hours_worked_per_week'],
    'date_hired' => $_POST['date_hired'],
    'beneficiary_name_relationship' => $_POST['beneficiary_name_relationship'],
    'proposed_name_insured_activity' => $_POST['proposed_name_insured_activity'],
    'used_tobacco_products' => $_POST['used_tobacco_products'],
    'email_address' => $_POST['email_address'],
    'spouse' => $_POST['spouse'],
    'sex_spouse' => $_POST['sex_spouse'],
    'spouse_dob' => $_POST['spouse_dob'],
    'children1' => $_POST['children1'],
    'sex_children1' => $_POST['sex_children1'],
    'children1_dob1' => $_POST['children1_dob1'],
    'children2' => $_POST['children2'],
    'sex_children2' => $_POST['sex_children2'],
    'children2_dob2' => $_POST['children2_dob2'],
    'children3' => $_POST['children3'],
    'sex_children3' => $_POST['sex_children3'],
    'children3_dob3' => $_POST['children3_dob3'],
    'children4' => $_POST['children4'],
    'sex_children4' => $_POST['sex_children4'],
    'children4_dob4' => $_POST['children4_dob4'],
    'plan_units_of_coverage' => $_POST['plan_units_of_coverage'],
    'plan_modal_premium' => $_POST['plan_modal_premium'],
    'total_premium_due' => $_POST['total_premium_due'],
    'coverage_type' => $_POST['coverage_type'],
    'riders' => $_POST['riders'],
    'section_125' => $_POST['section_125'],
    'name_of_company' => $_POST['name_of_company'],
    'replacement' => $_POST['replacement'],
    'plans_option' => $_POST['plans_option']
];



$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mysqlpass";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 'benefits_form');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$str = implode(",", $formData);
//echo "Connected successfully";

//$str = json_encode($formData);
//dd($str);
//$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_form (form_data) VALUES ('$str')";  
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_form (requested_effective_date, employer_group_name, group_number, billing_mode, other, proposed_name_insured, ssn, member_number, sex, age,
birth_date, daytime_phone_number, home_address, city, `state`, zip, jobtitle_occupation, hours_worked_per_week,
date_hired, beneficiary_name_relationship, proposed_name_insured_activity, used_tobacco_products, email_address, spouse,
sex_spouse, spouse_dob, children1, sex_children1, children1_dob1, children2, sex_children2, children2_dob2, children3, sex_children3, children3_dob3,
children4, sex_children4, children4_dob4, plan_units_of_coverage, plan_modal_premium, total_premium_due,
coverage_type, riders, section_125, name_of_company, replacement, plans_option) VALUES ('$str')";



if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record inserted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Could not insert record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

mysql create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_form` (
    `requested_effective_date` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `employer_group_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `group_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `billing_mode` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `other` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `proposed_name_insured` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `ssn` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `member_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `sex` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `age` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `birth_date` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `daytime_phone_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `home_address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `city` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `state` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `zip` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `jobtitle_occupation` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `hours_worked_per_week` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `date_hired` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `beneficiary_name_relationship` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `proposed_name_insured_activity` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `used_tobacco_products` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `email_address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `spouse` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `sex_spouse` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `spouse_dob` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `children1` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `sex_children1` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `children1_dob1` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `children2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `sex_children2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `children2_dob2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `children3` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `sex_children3` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `children3_dob3` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `children4` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `sex_children4` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `children4_dob4` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `plan_units_of_coverage` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `plan_modal_premium` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `total_premium_due` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `coverage_type` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `riders` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `section_125` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `name_of_company` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `replacement` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `plans_option` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci'
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I keep getting message 'Could not insert record: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' even though I have the same number of values for the number of columns.

I am expecting when a user enters data on the form and when they click submit form, the data should be saved on mysql table.  Then my plan is to export this data into a csv file for further reporting.

Comment: Why not try prepared statements instead

Comment: Please add the SQL used to create the table `tbl_form` so we can see which fields the table has. There has to be a mismatch between the table columns and the insert statement, but without the table structure we have nothing to compare it to.

Comment: You're creating a string containing comma-separated values, then wrapping it in quotes so that MySQL sees just a single string. hence the message. If you strip out the quotes in your query you'll have a series of bare text fields that will cause innumerable syntax errors, and will break for other reasons if your text contains quotes or commas. This code is so bad you'd do well to start again.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: So do I still need to use the implode function on my array to add data to mysql table?  Also instead of inserting each field in the insert query, can I use the $fields array name?

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: You will want to use data types appropriate for each value, not some generic `VARCHAR(50)` for everything. Consider: `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and integer values of various sorts. You'll also want to consider *normalizing* this structure.